# Nothing happening when using jQuery .removeClass

Tags: jquery

The .addClass works properly, however when I attempted to remove the same class on the same element when clicking the `.close` element, nothing happens. I've save the original element in `$currGallery`. When I console.log this on click, it shows the proper element object. Would appreciate any help!

```
    var $currGallery = null;

    var handler = function() {
      $currGallery = $(this);
      $(this).addClass("open-gallery");
      //$('.services > li').unbind( "click", handler );
    };

    $('.services > li').bind("click", handler);

    $('.close').click(function(){
      //console.log($currGallery);
      $currGallery.removeClass("open-gallery");
      //$('.services > li').bind( "click", handler );
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely (*without seeing your html*) the `.close` element, is inside the `.sevices > li` element as well. So when you click on the `.close` it correctly removes the class but the event also bubbles up to the `.sevices > li` which in turn re-adds the class.

If that is the case then on the `.close` handler you need to stop the propagation so that it never reaches the `li`.

```
$('.close').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();

  $currGallery.removeClass("open-gallery");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

based on my understanding of the issue you posted, I will suggest you use jquery toggleClass function.

below is a sample code, and a link to the documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>toggleClass demo</title>
  <style>
   p {
    margin: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    cursor: pointer;
   }
   .blue {
    color: blue;
   }
   .highlight {
    background: yellow;
   }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

 <p class="blue">Click to toggle</p>

 <script>
  $( "p" ).click(function() {
   $( this ).toggleClass( "highlight" );
  });
 </script>
 
</body>
</html>
```